# Do I need to explicitly pass an object to my relationship. (SQL Alchemy AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instaince_state')

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been working on a web app for work and I've run into an issue creating objects of my db.Model. I have a ShiftStamp form which lets people enter the shift they worked, however when they submit it I get this error

```
(SQL Alchemy AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instaince_state')
```

Original Code:
Users()

```py
class Users(People, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('people.id'), primary_key=True)
    #password = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    system_level_id = db.Column(db.String(50), ForeignKey('systemlevels.level'), nullable=False,  default='GROUND')
    system_level = db.relationship('SystemLevels', back_populates='users')
    #make sure to uncoment Campaigns along with this
    #candidacies = db.relationship('Campaigns', back_populates="candidate")
    admin_campaigns = db.relationship('Campaigns', secondary=admins, back_populates="admins")
    shiftstamps = db.relationship('ShiftStamps', back_populates="user")
```

ShiftStamps()

```py
class ShiftStamps(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shiftstamps'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = db.relationship('Users', back_populates='shiftstamps')
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    end_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    minutes= db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    activity_id = db.Column(db.String(50), ForeignKey('activities.activity'))
    activity = db.relationship("Activities", back_populates='shiftstamps')
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

```py
class Activities(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'activities'
    activity = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    shiftstamps = db.relationship("ShiftStamps", back_populates="activity")
```

This is prepopulated with activity as the primary_key
| activity |
| -------- |
| admin|
|calling|
|canvass|
|litdrop|
In my route I query for each value as a list since [values] can be passed [into SelectField](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.SelectField) instead of [(value,label)]
route

```py
@shift_route.route('/shift_add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def shift_add():
    form = ShiftStampForm()
    choiceMath = [(str(u.id), str(u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name)) for u in Users.query.order_by('first_name')]
    form.user.choices = choiceMath
    form.activity.choices = [str(a.activity) for a in Activities.query.order_by()]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        
        founduser = Users.query.filter_by(id=form.user.data).first()
        shiftstamp = ShiftStamps(user_id=founduser.id, start_time=datetime.combine(form.date.data, datetime.strptime(form.start_time.data, '%H:%M:%S').time()),
            end_time=datetime.combine(form.date.data, datetime.strptime(form.end_time.data, '%H:%M:%S').time()),
            activity=form.activity.data
            )
        shiftstamp.minutes = shiftstamp.end_time - shiftstamp.start_time.total_seconds() / 60
        comparedShift = ShiftStamps.query.filter_by(user_id=shiftstamp.user_id, start_time=shiftstamp.start_time).first()
        if comparedShift:
            flash("This Shift Already Exists.", category='error')
        else:
            db.session.add(shiftstamp)
            db.session.commit()

            form.user.data = ''
            form.date.data = ''
            form.start_time.data = ''
            form.end_time.data = ''
            form.activity.data = ''
            flash("Shift Added Successfully!", category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template('/shift/shift_add.html', form=form)
```

I modeled my classes after the described Many to One relationship pattern in the [SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html). The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995071/sql-alchemy-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-sa-instance-state) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083772/sqlalchemy-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-sa-instance-state) explain how I need to pass an instance of my user to the ShiftStamp() I'm creating in my route, however this requires querying for that user. This is the code where I do that

```py
@shift_route.route('/shift_add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def shift_add():
    form = ShiftStampForm()
    choiceMath = [(str(u.id), str(u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name)) for u in Users.query.order_by('first_name')]
    form.user.choices = choiceMath
    form.activity.choices = [str(a.activity) for a in Activities.query.order_by()]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        founduser = Users.query.filter_by(id=form.user.data).first()
        shiftstamp = ShiftStamps(user_id=founduser.id, user=founduser, start_time=datetime.combine(form.date.data, datetime.strptime(form.start_time.data, '%H:%M:%S').time()),
            end_time=datetime.combine(form.date.data, datetime.strptime(form.end_time.data, '%H:%M:%S').time()),
            activity=form.activity.data
            )
        shiftstamp.minutes = shiftstamp.end_time - shiftstamp.start_time.total_seconds() / 60
        comparedShift = ShiftStamps.query.filter_by(user_id=shiftstamp.user_id, start_time=shiftstamp.start_time).first()
        if comparedShift:
            flash("This Shift Already Exists.", category='error')
        else:
            db.session.add(shiftstamp)
            db.session.commit()

            form.user.data = ''
            form.date.data = ''
            form.start_time.data = ''
            form.end_time.data = ''
            form.activity.data = ''
            flash("Shift Added Successfully!", category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template('/shift/shift_add.html', form=form)
```

And yet it still doesn't work for some reason and I get the same error

I've also thought that one solution that has worked for the production of my app is just leave out the relationship keyword and work with ForeignKeys but that seems like going around a problem instead of using this as an opportunity to learn and find the solution that will help me for the future

Comment: You're already passing the user's `id`, and this is sufficient to "create" the relationship.  Your error is probably related to `activity`.

Comment: Yes, what is `type(form.activity.data)`? If it is a `list`, then what is `type(form.activity.data[0])`?

Comment: I find it super frustrating that in the error it won't tell me where the attribute that has no instance is, just the line at which it happens which can tunnel down very far. I've added the activities class to my original question. It is also a many to one relationship with ShiftStamp()

Comment: @GordThompson I'm assuming it would be a string since I'm passing a list of string values to represent the `(value, label )` pairs for the choices. I also am pretty sure SelectField() always returns a string and you need to use the the kwarg `coerce=` to change that

Comment: @snakecharmerb i just realized this is the issue I'm not passing to `activity_id` I'd like to clarify though, as long as I'm passing to `user_id` and `activity_id` I don't need to pass to `user` or `activity`

Comment: That's correct.